# Haskell Refresh a variables value

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to refresh a variable value, each time I make a recursion of a function. To make it simple I will give you an example.

Lets say we give to a function a number (n) and it will return the biggest mod it can have, with numbers smaller of itself.

```
{- Examples:
  n=5 `mod` 5
  n=5 `mod` 4
  n=5 `mod` 3
  n=5 `mod` 2
  n=5 `mod` 1
-}

example :: Integer -> Integer
example n
    |  n `mod` ...  >  !The biggest `mod` it found so far!  && ... > 0
       = !Then the biggest `mod` so far will change its value.
    |  ... = 0 !The number we divide goes 0 then end! = 0
```

Where ... = recursion ( I think)

I don't know how I can describe it better. If you could help me it would be great. :)

Comment: add second argument to function, like `example n acc = ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as you described:

```
example :: Integer -> Integer
example n = biggestRemainder (abs n) 0
    where
        biggestRemainder 0 biggestRemainderSoFar = biggestRemainderSoFar
        biggestRemainder divisor biggestRemainderSoFar = biggestRemainder (divisor - 1) newBiggestRemainder
            where
                thisRemainder = n `mod` divisor
                newBiggestRemainder = case thisRemainder > biggestRemainderSoFar of
                    True -> thisRemainder
                    False -> biggestRemainderSoFar
```

This function can also be written more easily as

```
example2 :: Integer -> Integer
example2 0 = 0
example2 n = maximum $ map (n `mod`) [1..(abs n)]
```

Comment: ahm why do you use a `case (thisRemainder > biggest..)of True ..` and not an if statement?

Comment: or `max thisRemainder biggestRemainderSoFar`

Comment: I hate if-then-else. It should have just been a prelude function `if :: Bool -> a -> a -> a`. As for `max`, I usually answer questions with code that doesn't depend on other code, unless that other code is providing something significant. In this case, if you replaced all of that `case` with `max`, the code would have very little in parallel with question, so it would be harder for the asker to understand.